# WHY in XP is it NOT POSSIBLE to set the Folder Options view for ALL folders

Tags: windows-xp, default-settings, user-folders

There are NO answers because of the impossibility. The bags business is useless, NO magic codes for any view. Folder Options useless because (1) whatever you do does not stick, and (2) your thousand plus folders will not all have the same view.

One is stuck doing each and every folder manually with ZERO help.

If *you* as a reader dislike these facts, rough tough tissue paper.
  Deleting my response has zero effect on the above.

Comment: The question is why are you still using it?

Comment: @Moab did you noticed the same user posted the question as answer there and got deleted?

Comment: See this page @Robert Baer>>>>>>>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/813711

Answer (score 1):

The general method for setting Folder Option has been around since XP forward. In Explorer, set a root folder the way you want (columns and details), then (in Explorer still, Tools, Folder Options, View, Apply to All folders.  Make sure all folders have been checked (selected) below. You may need to run the process a couple of times as it it not perfect.

xPlorer2 (zabkat.net) still support ZP and keeps folders exceedingly well arranged.  I use this myself and have done for years.